# Android, reading "NULL" from inputstream - interpretation

Tags: java, android, null

What could be a reason and what is proper interpretation (why it happens) of returning **null** in readline in code below:

```
if (socket != null) {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    out.write("ABC\n");
    out.flush();
    respond = in.readLine();
 }
```

I'm sure my server sends answer (sending some string) but sometimes code above give me **null** in respond.
Regards,
Artik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs  "the contents of the line or null if no characters were read before the end of the reader has been reached."

So there is no more input.

Comment: Yes thank you, but what I have to do if I get the null? Back to read next line or close socket (inputstream) to do reconnection? It is strange for me that answer from my server is recognizing as "null" instead of its original sended data.

Comment: @Artik The peer has closed the connection. You have no option but to close your end.